# Import Excel spreadsheets with different structures into an Access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

My current Access database uses a SQL insert statement to pull data from an Excel spreadsheet into a table. I now need to be able to get more data from another Excel spreadsheet (with different field names but same information) into the same table, is that possible? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Show us your `SQL` statement as well as spreadsheet screenshot. User `Docmd.TransferSpreadSheet` method to import data from excel to access in efficient manner.

Comment: Create a new SQL insert statement.

Comment: I would recommend importing the second worksheet as a new temp table and using an append query to add it to the old table as this will let you have different filed names at the start. After the query is done, use VBA to remove the imported table.